# How do I loop through a multidimensional array with foreach without knowing how many items there are?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that is like this:

```
Array
(
    [count] => 2
    [results] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [title] => My Title 1
                    [description] => My amazing description
                    [Images] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [pic_url] => https://my.pic.url/01/pic01-001.jpg
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [title] => My Title 2
                    [description] => Yet another amazing description
                    [Images] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Array
                                (
                                    [pic_url] => https://my.pic.url/02/pic02-001.jpg
                                )

                            [1] => Array
                                (
                                    [pic_url] => https://my.pic.url/02/pic02-002.jpg
                                )

                        )

                )



        )

)
```

There may be 1 item or 100 products in an array, each of which may have between 1-5 `[Images]`. How can I loop through each of them so that in the end I have something like:

```
 Title: 
    My Title 2
 Description:
    Yet another amazing description
 Images: 
    https://my.pic.url/02/pic02-001.jpg
    https://my.pic.url/02/pic02-002.jpg
```

I was able to get the title for example with `$decoded['results']['0']['title']` but I can't figure out how to display each of the titles and for each of them the unknown (1 to 5) number of image urls.

Comment: You know that you can get the size of an array with `count($array)`, you don't need to know it, don't you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use `foreach` here. Also, make sure you start by iterating through your `result` key like `$arr['result']`. if this code will be placed in the front-end, you can do something like this:

```
$arr = array( /* your array content */ );

foreach ($arr['results'] as $result) {
    ?>
    <div>
        <div>Title:<?= $result['title'] ?></div>
        <div>Description:<?= $result['description'] ?></div>
        <div>
            Images:
            <?php foreach ($result['Images'] as $image) { ?>
                <div><?= $image['pic_url'] ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much :)

Comment: Im glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your questions it's pretty easy. Loop through each of the results then within the foreach have another foreach which loops through the images. For example

```
foreach($product as $prod)
{
 //logic goes here
 foreach($prod['images'] as $img)
 {
   //do stuff with image
 }

}
```